# Using Word Interop to Watermark doc and docx

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

Is there a way to use word interop (for instance) to watermark a doc or docx file?

Any solution would be good, but it is going to have to work from within C#.

I.e. supply the code with a byte[] and it will have to add a watermark and spit out a new byte[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using Aspose Words, the C# library for creating and modifying Word documents without actually needing Word.

Have a look at http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/howto-add-a-watermark-to-a-document.html.

No, I don't own Aspose shares, unfortunately...

Comment: i don't think it's a problem for him using microsoft interop